# Docker bind mount mode forced to read-only

Tags: docker

I'd like to build an application using docker, and to get the built files back to the host using a build mount, but I cannot get the docker image to be able to write to the mounted directory. Here is a minimal `Dockerfile` that reproduces the issue

```
FROM alpine:3.7
WORKDIR /app
RUN touch /app/build/test.txt
```

The command that I use to run this build is `docker build --rm -v "$(pwd)/build:/app/build" .` The error I get is shown below:

```
$ docker build --rm -v "$(pwd)/build:/app/build" .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 81.29 MB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine:3.7
 ---> 34ea7509dcad
Step 2/3 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> b0c4ac704af7
Removing intermediate container 234ef41fd395
Step 3/3 : RUN touch /app/build/test.txt
 ---> Running in e095ed8b29d5
touch: /app/build/test.txt: Read-only file system
```

I am running on Fedora 27, with Docker v1.13.1. There is a `docker` group on my machine to allow running docker commands without `sudo`, as explained [here](https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tools/docker/docker-installation.html)

I have tried the following without success:

- Calling the docker command with `sudo`
- Disabling SELinux (I keep it disabled at the moment)
- Adding the `z`/`Z` mount option to the volume, as explained [here](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/06/using-volumes-with-docker-can-cause-problems-with-selinux/) (`-v "$(pwd)/build:/app/build:Z"`)
- Adding the `rw` mount option (`-v "$(pwd)/build:/app/build:rw"`)
- Calling `docker build` with no `build` directory on the host

Comment: `-v` is not a valid option for docker build. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/. Are you running a standard docker install, or is that customized by redhat?

Comment: To add to @BMitch's comment: the output of `docker build` is always an image and can never use or produce resources from the host, outside the directory tree that gets passed as the input.  There is no way to run `docker build` and have it produce a binary or other artifacts on the host.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, `docker build` does not support the `-v` option. What I was trying to do with a Dockerfile and `docker build` should done with a `docker run` command instead:

```
docker run -i -v $(pwd)/build:/app/build alpine:3.7 << EOF
 touch /app/build/test.txt
 ... other commands ...
EOF
```